# rstrip() will not remove what I tell it to

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the `\n` in a file using `rstrip('\n')`. I have checked other questions similar but could not find an answer. Here is my code -

```
numFile = open(sys.stdin.read(),'r')
numFile = numFile.rstrip('\n')
```

When I run the program, it says that my file doesn't exist because it adds a `\n` to the end.

Comment: `sys.stdin.read()` ends in a newline. *that* file doesn't exist. Also `open(...)` returns a file object, which doesn't implement `rstrip`.

Comment: Any reason you're using `sys.stdin.read()` and not using `input()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the limited context of your question, I believe you are trying to strip the `\n`  off of the file name, not the contents. Try this:

```
numFile = open(sys.stdin.read().rstrip('\n'),'r')
```